# How do I "unhook" / de-register jQuery so that it's not called as part of wp_footer();?

Tags: theme-development, functions, themes, jquery, hooks

I need to "unhook" jQuery from my `wp_footer()` ... it's being called automatically and I'm looking for something I can add to functions.php which prevents it from being called a second time in the footer (since I need to call it in the header)

*please no editorial comments about why calling in the footer is better*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to *unregister* the script; that would make it *unavailable* to be enqueued. Rather, you want to *dequeue* the script.

You have two choices:

1. If you know the callback function through which `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' )` is called, you can simply call `remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'callback_function_name' )`
2. More likely, you won't know the callback function (or jQuery will be enqueued as a dependency by another script), in which case, you can dequeue it directly, which you would do via [`wp_dequeue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script).

e.g.

```
function theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery() {
     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'theme_slug_dequeue_footer_jquery', 11 );
```

Note: that *priority* is probably fairly important, since you'll need to ensure that your *dequeue* call fires *after* the *enqueue* call.

#### Edit

> I'm customizing this theme from the default TwentyEleven theme. It seems as though it's the theme itself that's hooking WordPress and not a plugin. I looked in the default functions.php and I don't see any wp_enqueue_script() in there. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Are you by chance viewing the Showcase Template (i.e. [`showcase.php`](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentyeleven/1.3/showcase.php))? Note that it enqueues a custom script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyeleven-showcase', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/showcase.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2011-04-28' );
```

It adds jQuery to its dependents array, meaning that WordPress will first enqueue jQuery, and *then* enqueue `twentyeleven-showcase`. So, that might be the source of the mystery jQuery enqueue.

(There's also a `wp_enqueue_script()` call in `/inc/theme-options.php`, but I don't think that one would be impacting your front-end script-enqueueing.)

Comment: You should use the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' hook, not wp_footer.

Comment: "*You should use the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' hook, not wp_footer*" - not if you're trying to *remove* it from the footer. If it's been *enqueued* in the footer, then you'll need to call `remove_action()` on `wp_footer`.

Comment: Did some testing and you are correct.

Comment: Thanks so much Chip!  Question: in terms of tracking down / finding the offending call to jQuery in the footer.  I normally use a boilerplate theme, but for a complex reasons, I'm customizing this theme from the default *TwentyEleven* theme.  It seems as though it's the theme itself that's hooking WordPress and not a plugin.  I looked in the default `functions.php` and I don't see any `wp_enqueue_script()` in there.  Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: See updated answer re: Twenty Eleven script enqueueing.

Comment: + 1 for "_You don't want to unregister the script; that would make it unavailable to be enqueued. Rather, you want to dequeue the script._". Most **important** note <- Should be stated bold ore better as h1-headline :) Btw: Shouldn't the hook be `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a priority of 9999. Or if you're using wp_footer, then maybe with a priority of `0`. Might be too late else.

Answer (score 1):

the function to deregister any script is :

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

But the problem you have is different , if what I understand correctly - you have jQury included TWICE , once on header and once of footer . This is some plugin or theme function that is executed incorrectly - asking specifically to print in footer.. You might want to identify the problem better , for it can cause other problems ...

Anyhow, example hooks are : (one init , one print_scripts)

```
function dl_register_common_js() {
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
//add_action('init', 'dl_register_common_js'); // will deregister from head
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'dl_register_common_js');
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Question: in terms of tracking down / finding the offending call to jQuery in the footer.  I normally use a boilerplate theme, but for a complex reasons, I'm customizing this theme from the default *TwentyEleven* theme.  It seems as though it's the theme itself that's hooking WordPress and not a plugin.  I looked in the default `functions.php` and I don't see any `wp_enqueue_script()` in there.  Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: look also in header.php, footer.php and also in plugins (if you have them) . BTW - twentyeleven is a really bad choice for customizing ..